# NGINX redirect with trailing backslash

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want to redirect
`www.foo.bar/baz` & `www.foo.bar/baz/` to `www.foo.bar/qux`

I have the following in my NGINX config
`rewrite ^/baz$ /qux permanent;`

This redirects `www.foo.bar/baz` to `www.foo.bar/qux` but  `www.foo.bar/baz/` to `www.foo.bar`

If I change the config as follows
`rewrite ^/baz/$ /qux permanent;`
or
`rewrite ^/baz[^/]$ /qux permanent;`

Both `www.foo.bar/ba` & `www.foo.bar/baz/` redirect to `www.foo.bar`

How can I make the trailing `/` be respected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the syntax below

```
rewrite ^/baz/?$ /qux permanent;
```

the `?` should tell nginx that the the previous character (slash in this case) is optional

In case you wonder why `?` just get a reference of **Regular Expressions** syntax